# Using tag question with one

Tags: tag-questions

> One should study hard.

What is the question tag for the sentence?

Should I use *they* , *he*, or *one*?

Comment: Sorry, was confusing question tag with the tags for questions on SE. You'd use one: "One should study hard, shouldn't one?"

Comment: Can i use he or they

Comment: If you're going to use this very dated style, you'd better go the whole hog with 'shouldn't one?' But real people say 'Students (etc) should study hard, shouldn't they?'

Comment: AE: Nobody I know would ever use "One should..." in this way. It sounds weird to the point of being wrong. More's a pity: some other languages you wouldn't have to specify who you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

One should study hard, shouldn't one? 
One can be used as a subject of question tag because it is a personal pronoun and can refer to the subject one.

One should do one's duty.

Answer (score 0):

**One should study hard** is antiquated (old-fashioned) but the grammar is good. 
Depending on the context you are writing in, you could say any of the options you suggested.

Use '**You should study hard.**' if you are addressing one person in particular.
Use '**He should study hard.**' if you are talking about one person to another.
Use '**One should study hard.**' if you are being formal.

Be aware that some people would view the use of **'One'** as too formal, and it is often associated with Upper Class Britain, and the Royal Family!

Comment: The OP is asking about tag questions, that is, how the create a matching tag question for the statement in their example. They were not asking if they should change the initial statement.

Comment: Note that the word "antiquated" has negative connotations which aren't necessarily appropriate here.

Answer (score -1):

> "Shouldn't they?"

"one" is treated as an indefinate pronoun in the question tag